# How to choose a value from a list in Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a list of this form:

```
<span class="trigger">
<i class="fa fa-list-ol fa-lg"></i>
<span>&ensp;1000 rows&emsp;</span></span>

<div id="tool-row-menu" class="mdc-menu mdc-menu--open" tabindex="-1" style="transform-origin: left top; left: 0px; top: 0px;">

<ul class="mdc-menu__items mdc-list" role="menu" aria-hidden="true">
<li data-value="5" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">5</li>
<li data-value="20" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">20</li>
<li data-value="100" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">100</li>
<li data-value="500" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">500</li>
<li data-value="1000" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">1000</li>
<li data-value="2000" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">2000</li>
<li data-value="5000" class="mdc-list-item" role="menuitem" tabindex="0">5000</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have entered the drop down list but am not being able to select the option that I want: 5000.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()=' 1000 rows ']").click() #works

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='5000']").click()  #error
```

The error message :
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[text()='5000']"}

I could only find answers for lists starting from 'select' and having 'options'. Since I am only a beginner at Selenium, I would want someone to point out the error that I am making.

Comment: have you tried ```driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-value='5000']").click()```

Comment: Use webdriver waits to allow for you to pick up the second element appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find not with a text, but with another attribute. For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-value="5000"]).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,30)            
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//li[@data-value='5000']"))).click()
```

You want to add some wait for the element to popup to click.

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```